# Perl, passing array into subroutine, dealing with undeclared variables

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I have a sub with some firmly variables and variables I declare and use within the sub, but when I call this sub I can't declare them.

for example:

```
sub func{
my ($firm1, $firm2, $possible) = @_;
...
if($possible eq "smth"){ # in case i passed this scalar
}
elsif($possible eq ("smth else" or undef/i_don_t_know)){ # in case i didn't passed this var, but i need it as at least undef or smth like that
}

func(bla, bla, bla); # ok
func(bla, bla); # not ok
```

When I tried that, I got an error

> "Use of uninitialized value $possible in string eq at test.pl line
>   ..."

How can I correct this?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with declarations.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed code that is compilable under `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed code that will compile under `use strict` and `use warnings`. Making up stuff that isn't even Perl code makes your question far too ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with declarations. If you pass only two parameters to a subroutine that begins with

```
    my ( $firm1, $firm2, $possible ) = @_;
```

then `$possible` is *undefined*, which means it is set to the special value `undef`, which is like `NULL`, `None`, `nil` etc. in other languages

As you have seen, you can't compare an undefined value without causing a warning message, and you must first used the `defined` operator to check that a variable is defined

I *think* you want to test whether `$possible` is both defined and set to the string `smth`. You can do it this way

```
sub func {

    my ( $firm1, $firm2, $possible ) = @_;

    if ( defined $possible and $possible eq 'smth' ) {

        # Do something
    }
}

func( qw/ bla bla bla / );    # ok
func( qw/ bla bla / );        # now also ok
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exact what i need

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem with a declaration, but rather passing an undefined value.

There's several ways of handling this:

- Test for `defined` on the variable
- Set a 'default' `$possible //= "default_value"` will conditionally assign if undefined.

Or do something else entirely.